# vboxapi COM API not working

Tags: python, virtualbox, pywin32

I have the virtualbox 5.0.10 Python sdk in my source root, but when I run my code the program will fail:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xiao/.PyCharm50/config/scratches/scratch", line 2, in <module>
    mgr=vboxapi.VirtualBoxManager()
  File "C:\Users\xiao\Desktop\test\vboxapi\__init__.py", line 1018, in __init__
    self.platform = PlatformMSCOM(dPlatformParams)
  File "C:\Users\xiao\Desktop\test\vboxapi\__init__.py", line 513, in __init__
    win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('VirtualBox.Session')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 540, in EnsureDispatch
    disp_class = CLSIDToClass.GetClass(str(disp_clsid))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\CLSIDToClass.py", line 46, in GetClass
    return mapCLSIDToClass[clsid]
KeyError: '{7844AA05-B02E-4CDD-A04F-ADE4A762E6B7}'
```

Here is my code: (really simple, right?)

```
import vboxapi
mgr=vboxapi.VirtualBoxManager()
```

This program is buggy under Python 2.7.6, but runabble under Python 3.4.0.

Why? How can I fix that?